# how to extend jquery UI dialog button with parameter?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

This is a sample code i used for creating a jquery Dialog. Im creating JQuery dialog and extending it.

```
   function dialog_box(dynDiv, rootTemplate) {
            var dialog_buttons = rootTemplate.buttons;
            $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog({
            hide: "explode",
                buttons:{},
                title: rootTemplate.etype,               
                text: rootTemplate.text,
                resizable: true,
                minWidth: 200,
                minHeight: 150
            });

            var mydialog = $("#" + dynDiv.id).dialog()
            var buttons = mydialog.dialog("option", "buttons"); // getter         
            $.extend(buttons, dialog_buttons);
```

Dialog buttons is a json structure like below.

```
{
    "buttons": [
        {
            "id": "confirm",
            "text": "Yes",
             click: testconfirm
        }
    ]
}
```

so if i need to pass a parameter like below how can mention that while extending?

```
click({param1: "Hello", param2: "World"}, testfunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the click handler as below by wrapping it inside an anonymous function:

```
{
   "buttons": [{
        "id": "confirm",
        "text": "Yes",
         click: function() {
             var paramObj = {param1: "Hello", param2: "World"};
             testconfirm(paramObj);
         }
    }]
}
```